# How does the voltage drop of the body diode in a SiC MOSFET depend on Vgs?

Tags: mosfet

The voltage drop of the body diode of a MOSFET depends on the gate to source voltage Vgs. Does anyone know why? It is not really a simple diode.

[image]

Comment: Please link the data sheet.

Comment: With higher gate voltage present, you have both the body diode and the MOSFET conducting current, hence lower forward voltage drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the negative gate-source-voltage increases in amplitude, or V<sub>GS</sub> goes further negative, the channel becomes "more off" (if that's the correct definition, probably not) so the body diode becomes more and more "apparent" causing higher voltage drop for the same forward current.

When V<sub>GS</sub> = 0 the MOSFET will not be completely off (remember the leakage current). In other words, showing relatively lower resistance than that for V<sub>GS</sub> < 0. Since this resistance is in parallel with the body diode, part of the source-drain current will be stolen by the channel itself, causing less current flow through actual diode, bringing lower drop.

Tried to illustrate below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM2rpP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic above, R<sub>ch</sub> is the channel resistance, and R<sub>on</sub> is the on resistance. The arrows indicate non-zero (or non-negligible) currents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known behavior of SiC MOSFETs in third quadrant. In contrast to a Si MOSFET, the SiC MOSFET Gate-channel is not completely closed at V_GS = 0 V, and partially conducts current, so at V_GS = 0 V the voltage drop will be lower as for a negative value of V_GS.

See for instance "Power Cycling Methods for SiC MOSFETs" of Herold et al. or "Third Quadrant Behavior of SiC MOSFETs" of Callanan et al. for more details.